# Django: How to order a queryset and move some items to end of the queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a queryset in my Django application:

```
databytes_all = DataByte.objects
```

Each item in the `databytes_all` queryset has many attributes but one of them is `publish_date`.

I'd like to order the queryset by `publish_date`, however if `publish_date` is `None`, I'd like the item to be at the end of the queryset.

This is what I'm trying but it's not working:

```
databytes_all = DataByte.objects
```

Make a queryset: filter out all of the publish dates that are None

```
no_date = databytes_all.filter(publish_date=None)
```

Make anohther queryset: exclude all of the items where publish date is none, then order the remaining items by publish date

```
databytes_with_date = databytes_all.order_by('-publish_date').exclude(publish_date=None)
```

Now combine the two querysets (however this doesnt work- the items with no publish date are first in the list when I want them to be last)

```
databytes = databytes_with_date | no_date
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to filter, you can specify that the `NULL` should be last with:

```
from django.db.models import F

databytes_all.order_by(F('publish_date').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

We here thus make use of an [**`F`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) where we call the [**`.desc(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc). This method has a `nulls_last=…` parameter that we can use to specify that items with `NULL` should be selected as the last records.

This will sort with:

```
SELECT …
FROM …
ORDER BY publish_date IS NULL, publish_date DESC
```

since `False`/`0` is considered less than `True`/`1`, it will thus move the items with `publish_date` to the bottom of the records you retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

In Django, you can combine a lot of QuerySet using chain
try this:

```
from itertools import chain

...

combined_results = list(chain(databytes_with_date, no_date))
```